# How to remove package name from start of function from a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

So I have a node module, but I wanna know how to turn `something.somethingElse()` into `somethingElse()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the function doesn't use `this`:

```
const somethingElse = something.somethingElse;
or 
const { somethingElse } = require('something');
or 
import { somethingElse } from 'something';
```

if it does need `this`, you'll need to use `bind` so `this` is set correctly:

```
const somethingElse = something.somethingElse.bind(something);
```

And the fun thing is that you probably won't know if it need `this` unless you try it and it throws an error!